# How to specify a host ip address to sendmail

Tags: linux, ubuntu-10.04, sendmail

I have sendmail installed on a server running Ubuntu 10.04.  I need to be able to send email to my companies email server from this machine, but I am not currently able to.  A rep in the IP department determined that my issue was that the IP address my server is resolving for the company mail server is it's external address and I need to be connecting to it's internal address (due to the way they have routing rules configured).  He gave me the IP address I need to connect to and instructed me to set mail.mycompany.com to resolve to this IP address.  How do I accomplish this?  (I tried /etc/hosts but found out very quickly that does not work for sendmail).

Comment: Where is the sendmail server located? Is it local to the company's email server?

Answer (score 1):

You can check what the resolver is giving for the mail server is to use the command `getent hosts mail.example.com` using your mail server in place of mail.example.com.  If this isn't giving the right result sendmail won't either.  Also try the command `host -a example.com` to see what mail sever address you are getting from DNS.  It should return the internal mail server.

It may also be possible the external IP is hard-coded into the sendmail configuration.  Check the configuration file for the external address of the mail server.  If I remember right it should `/etc/sendmail.conf`.

Verify your changes to `/etc/hosts` to do this.  Check that the hosts line in `/etc/nsswitch.conf` has files listed before DNS.  Restart `nscd` after making changes to `/etc/hosts`.  Then rerun the genent command above.  The hosts line should read like:

```
192.0.2.5  mail.example.com
```

Is there any reason you are using sendmail rather than postfix or exim?